# Random Keyframe Positions Every Iteration to Create Falling "Matrix Code"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm attempting to make an HTML web page with animated CSS classes on many independent DIVs moving to their own randomly generated positions. I have 20 elements with randomly generated characters falling from the top of the page and dissipating as they move along their y-axis (like the Matrix code).

**EDIT:** [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yLzkvb9e/) Remember the range is wide, so sometimes the group of characters generate far off to the right (outside the small viewing window)

Generating random char in top JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    });

    function generateChar()
    {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789«‘¥~‹÷´`≠¡ˆ()][¶#@…•–!£$%&/?^*é§°ç_:è+òàù,.-";
        text = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        return text; 
    }

</script>
```

HTML of 20 divs

```
<div id="m1 " class="timeSpan movement"></div>
...
<div id="m20" class="timeSpan movement"></div>
```

JavaScript: Here I've randomly generated characters (successfully) but only 1 random position. All the elements start in the same position instead of starting from their own spots.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("m1 ").innerHTML = generateChar();
    ...
    document.getElementById("m20").innerHTML = generateChar();


    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){

        var xRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 2000); 
        var yBegRan = Math.round(Math.random() * 150); 
        var yEndRan = Math.round(Math.random() * (2000 - 650) + 650);
        var secRan  = Math.round(Math.random() * (20));  

        var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("style")),
        rule = " moveMinus {\
            0%   {\
                opacity: 1;\
            }\
            100%   {\
                opacity: 0; \
            }\
            from {\
                top: " + yBegRan + "px; left: " + xRandom + "px;\
            }\
            to {\
                top: " + yEndRan + "px; left: " + xRandom + "px;\
            }\
        }";

        if (CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
            style.sheet.insertRule("@keyframes" + rule, 0);
        } else if (CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
            style.sheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes" + rule, 0);
        }

        divs[i].innerHTML = makeid(); 
    }
</script>
```

CSS

```
.body-m{
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.movement{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px; 
  color: limegreen;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

@keyframes moveMinus {
  from { top: 0px; left: 21px; }
  to   { top: 600px; left: 21px; }
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.timeSpan{
  animation: moveMinus 7s infinite;
}
```

How do I properly iterate through the DIVs' styles?

Comment: Can create stacksnippets ,  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, I'll edit my post with a link

Comment: If using CSS, I think you're going to have to add a different keyframe for each iteration and then add the keyframe to the specific id. However to me it seems like this would be better done with javascript/jquery.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I had individual keyframes before (which worked) but if I wanted to do 200 to 300 characters it would get repetitive fast. I'll look into jQuery

Comment: @coozin As for the coding it shouldn't really make any difference if you have 10 or 1000 because you just loop over it anyway, so you just write it once. However I was thinking more along the lines that your CSS is just going to keep growing and growing unless you can somehow "garbage collect" or reuse the past keyframes. Come to think of it, it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: This might interest you: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17285/make-the-matrix-digital-rain-using-the-shortest-amount-of-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I just made this fiddle, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLzkvb9e/1/), I'm not sure that's what you wanted but I get a result that you can easily edit =)

Here is the main function :

```
function setDiv(_div){
        var xRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 2000); 
        var yBegRan = Math.round(Math.random() * 600); 
        var yEndRan = Math.round(Math.random() * (2000 - 650) + 650);
        var secRan  = Math.round(Math.random() * (20)) + 10;  

        _div.style.opacity = 1;
        _div.style.top = yBegRan +"px";
        _div.style.animationDuration = secRan +"s";
        _div.style.left = xRandom + "px";
        _div.innerHTML = generateChar();
    }
```

Comment: **You did it!** I see what you did here: set the properties to the DIV instead so you could recycle the class and keyframe in the css. You also auto generated lots of DIVs.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function generateChar() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789«‘¥~‹÷´`≠¡ˆ()][¶#@…•–!£$%&/?^*é§°ç_:è+òàù,.-";
        text = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        return text;
    }

    var len = 500;
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    document.body.appendChild(style);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        var xRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 2000);
        var yBegRan = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
        var yEndRan = Math.round(Math.random() * (2000 - 650) + 650);
        var secRan = Math.round(Math.random() * (20));

        var rule = " moveMinus" + i +" {" 
        + "0%{opacity: 1;top:" 
        + yBegRan + "px; left:" 
        + xRandom + "px;"
        + "}" 
        + "100% {" 
        + "opacity: 0;top:"
        + yEndRan + "px; left:" 
        + xRandom + "px;" 
        + "}}";

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.left = (Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + "px";
        div.className = "timeSpan" + i;
        div.innerHTML = generateChar();

        if (!("webkitAnimation" in document.body.style)) {
            style.textContent += "." + div.className 
            +"{animation:moveMinus"+i+" "+Math.random() * 7
            +"s infinite;}\n" +"@keyframes" + rule;
        } else {

            style.textContent += "." + div.className 
            +"{-webkit-animation:moveMinus"+i+" "+Math.random() * 7
            +"s infinite;}\n" 
            +"@-webkit-keyframes" + rule;
        };

        document.body.appendChild(div)
    }
```

```css
.body-m {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*Base Class*/
 .movement {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: limegreen;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  color:lime;
}
```

```html
<body class="body-m"></body>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yLzkvb9e/2/