# Javascript Stripe about us faces

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to replicate something like the faces on https://stripe.com/about using Javascript.

I've tried to make a more basic version of this using jQuery but can't even get started, I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I've reiterated.

Comment: @dthms _"I've tried to make a more basic version of this using jQuery"_ Can include `html` , `css` , `js` tried at Question ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372533/random-keyframe-positions-every-iteration-to-create-falling-matrix-code/

Comment: If you don't have a started point, just 'view source' the link you mentioned in the question. Implement it and it still doesn't work, post the code you have tried for SO to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that they're doing all of it with [CSS keyframe animations](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/), but if you're looking to replicate the functionality quickly, I'd suggest looking into an animation framework like [greensock](http://greensock.com/get-started-js). With greensock you have the ability to create animations that will continue indefinitely like that, plus pause on hover etc.

Basic greensock syntax is very straightforward, and looks like this:

```
var moveinner = TweenMax.to(document.querySelector('.inner'), 30, {
  left: "-=300",
  ease: Power0.easeOut,
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true
})
```

Here's a really quick and dirty [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b0jfvryh/1/) of how greensock could approach that type of functionality. Obviously it would take a lot of cleaning up plus some conditions to prevent overlapping and such, but that should be enough to send you down the right road